# XTEND For-Loop indexcontrol in DomainmodelGenerator.xtend (XTEXT codegeneration project)

Tags: dsl, xtext, xtend

I worked through the Tutorials at eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation and get into expanding these samples. Working with the Domainmodel.xtext sample I generate a Java-Classfile for each entity as stated in the Tut.

The DSL specifies an arbitry number of features, aka class properties:

```
  Entity:
  'entity' name = ID 
          ('extends' superType = [Entity | QualifiedName])?
   '{'
   (features += Feature)*
   '}'
    ;
```

In DomainmodelGenerator.xtend then I added code to generate a JAVA-classconstructor. The XTEND-Forloop cycles through all arguements - looks like this:

```
def compile_Constructors(Entity e) '''
public «e.name.toFirstUpper»
       (
      «FOR f : e.features»
           «f.type.fullyQualifiedName» «f.name.toFirstUpper», 
      «ENDFOR»
        ) 
{}  
'''
```

**Problem**
With this the last parameter there is still a comma emitted. How can I get control in XTEND over the loopindex, to make the generator to emit legal JAVA code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
def compile_Constructors(Entity e) '''
    public «e.name.toFirstUpper»
           (
           «e.features.map[type.fullyQualifiedName + ' ' + name.toFirstUpper].join(', ')»
           ) 
    {}
'''
```

Comment: elegant works fine. I went on reading XTEND documentation. Learnt a multilinestring with ''' ''' is called a template, an the FOR-Loop Syntax covers this requirement with elegant syntax: 

`   
def compile_Constructors(Entity e) '''
    public «e.name.toFirstUpper»
           (
    «FOR f : e.features SEPARATOR ","»
         «f.type.fullyQualifiedName»            
                       «f.name.toFirstUpper» 
    «ENDFOR»
            ) 
    {
     
    }
`

Comment: sorry backticks for code was not working, and I run into 5 minute timeout for comments.

Answer (score 3):

The `«FOR»` loop has some options which are quite handy:

- `BEFORE string`
- `SEPARATOR string`
- `AFTER string`

These allows you to emit additional strings before, between and after items. If there are no items (empty list) none of them is emitted.

So in your case just use

```
«FOR f : e.features SEPARATOR ', '»
```